# How to use recent Boost versions with Travis CI

Tags: c++, boost, travis-ci

I have just started using [Travis-CI](http://www.travis-ci.org) and it works really well, but some of my projects require recent versions of Boost.  In particular, one requires Boost 1.59 or newer, and Travis-CI only has Boost 1.55 available.

Is there an easy way to get Boost >= 1.59 installed in a build container?

I can see some people are downloading and compiling Boost before they are compiling their own program, but this seems to me to be a waste of resources - surely there is a package available somewhere that can be used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

- Recall that Travis uses Ubuntu
- Remember that Canonical gives Lunchpad to build personal package archives (PPAs)
- So upload what you need (maybe taking it from Debian or more recent Ubuntu) to Launchpad
- Then use it on Travis

I am doing so in eg [this Travis recipe](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rquantlib/blob/master/.travis.yml#L22) against my [RQuantLib](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rquantlib.html) package which for testing needed a more recent [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org) library. By adding my own PPA I get a new binary than I would have from the distro.

Even if you don't (yet ;-) ) know how to create a package, you may well find an existing PPA with a newer Boost version.

Comment: Can this be done with the newer containers, or does it require sudo access and the older style of building?

Comment: It may require the old approach because of the package whitefish requirements.

Comment: Phone keyboard got the better of me: _whitelist_ requirements.